# Sessions and symlinks

Tags: php, apache, session

Is this possible with "read & write" sessions as symlinks?

php.ini:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php5"
```

In session file

```
var|s:3:"foo";
```

**Part without symlinks**

/var/lib/php5 dir:

```
sess_amuqt0u58nl8tulueenjqi1apcm5gnk99jaij3q55h5kivtu4t50
```

php output for session_id() === "amuqt0u58nl8tulueenjqi1apcm5gnk99jaij3q55h5kivtu4t50":

```
var_dump($_SESSION); // array("var"=>"foo")
```

**Part with symlinks**

/var/lib/php5 dir:

```
other_file
sess_amuqt0u58nl8tulueenjqi1apcm5gnk99jaij3q55h5kivtu4t50 > other_file
```

php output for session_id() === "amuqt0u58nl8tulueenjqi1apcm5gnk99jaij3q55h5kivtu4t50":

```
var_dump($_SESSION); // array()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No, _No Ideas_ as in not sure what you are actually asking

Comment: I want session file as symlink, but it doesn't work - $_SESSION var is empty

Comment: I am fairly sure you dont actually want to do this. Remember you get one session file _for each user_ active on your site. So you could have hundered at any one moment. It looks like you are assuming that all sessions get put into one file. Thats not the case.